# Adobe Illustrator Scripting - No Management for Units

Tags: scripting, adobe-illustrator, units-of-measurement

So, I searched through the documentation on AI CS6's Scripting Reference (JavaScript / though actually ECMAScript), and I cannot find anything for managing units, or unit conversion. Is it missing?

Photoshop uses ECMAScript's UnitValue object as a standard way for managing unit conversion, but I can't find anything for Illustrator. Illustrator functions do not accept UnitValue instances - they only accept doubles, in the "points" unit.

**How am I supposed to manage units in AI?**

Or, if nothing else, **how do I run conversions from a given unit to *points*?**

p.s. Why is it points anyway? Is that script-default? My current default unit is inches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to all your questions can be found in the Adobe Illustrator Scripting Guide [(CS6 on the Adobe home page)](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/cs6/Illustrator-Scripting-Guide.pdf) in the Measurement units section.  This section seem to remain unchanged for years.

In particular,

- "Illustrator uses points when communicating with your scripts
  *regardless of the current ruler units*"
- "If your script depends on [...] units other than points, it must perform any unit conversions needed to represent your measurements as points."
- Precise conversion rules: 1 inch = 72 points, 1 inch = 2.54 cm, 1 pica = 12 points

Answer (score 0):

Try setting required units without conversion (replace PIXELS to probably POINTS):

```
    //at start of script:
    var originalUnit=preferences.rulerUnits;//alert(originalUnit);
    preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;//alert(preferences.rulerUnits);

    //your main code here

    //at the end - restore units:
    preferences.rulerUnits = originalUnit;
```